# 404 error for mod_rewrite using SSL and MAMP

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, mamp

I am building an app in Zend Framework at the moment and testing it all locally. I have Mamp Pro as my web server and I have a self-signed SSL which all seems to work. My problem comes when I try to do mod_rewrite - I just get 404 pages.

The way I have things set up (which may not be the best way...)

---

In Mamp I have 2 virtualhosts set up both pointing to the same web directory (webroot/public/):

- secure.myapp.com
- myapp.com

In my public directory is my index.php file and my .htaccess file. The contents of the .htaccess file are:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I visit http://myapp.com everything routes as it should using the mod_rewrite. But when I go to https://secure.myapp.com the index page is fine, but URL routing stops working and it appears to be that the .htaccess file is being ignored.

In my ssl.conf I have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

Listen 443
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         dbm:/Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_scache
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex  file:/Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_mutex

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

SSLEngine on
DocumentRoot "/webroot/public"
ServerName secure.myapp.com
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_error_log
TransferLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_access_log

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl_cert/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl_key/server.key

CustomLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Does anybody have any ideas on this? I'll be sooooo appreciative of the help as it's seriously hindering my development!

Comment: Did you set `AllowOverride FileInfo` for that directory? And did you take a look into the error log?

Comment: Gumbo, I think my problem is that I am unable to set any Directory specific overrides using MAMP. I need to set <Directory /> in the VirtualHost listening on port 443, but when I try to do this MAMP won't let me start Apache. I think I have worked around it... See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm pretty sure that I have got this working. Basically, a big problem I had is that Mamp does not store vhosts.conf as an accessible file. Instead this is an aliased application file.

I think what happens is that the virtualhosts are all dynamically created all on the standard http port, in my case 80. However I needed to be able to access the port 433 vhost config to enable FileInfo. So my workaround is to ditch my .htaccess file and stick the following ALL into my ssl.conf file.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

Listen 443
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         dbm:/Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_scache
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex  file:/Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_mutex

<VirtualHost mysite.com:443>

    SSLEngine on
    DocumentRoot /webroot/secure
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin you@example.com
    ErrorLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_access_log

    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl_cert/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/ssl_key/server.key

    CustomLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_request_log \
              "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
            RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

            RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
            RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]

            RewriteLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/ssl_rewrite_log
            RewriteLogLevel 3
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

I had to add DOCUMENT_ROOT in front of my file and directory checks, and a forward slash in front of index.php. If I could have put this into a "Directory" then I think I could have avoided these changes, but Apache won't restart when I add this parameter.

The only thing I didn't try was adding the info to MAMP's httpd.conf, but I have a feeling the same restrictions may be in place.